# Leaflet - Map container is already initialized on page change

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am developing an app with angular I have integrated a complement that uses Leaflet to show a map with marks on specific points.

As I've said, I developed a component to reuse on different pages. But when I change between pages that use this component, it returns me the error:

```
ERROR Error: Map container is already initialized.
```

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mapDetails"></div>
```

**TS:**

```
export class MapDetailsComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() item!: SiteDetail;
  @Output() emitOptionSelected: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  public map: any;

  private initMap(): void {
    console.log(this.map);
    this.map = L.map('mapDetails', {
      center: [40.4379543,-3.6795367],
      zoom: 6
    });

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      minZoom: 6,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });

    tiles.addTo(this.map);
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadSites();
  }

  loadSites() {
    if(this.item) this.map.setView([this.item.latitude, this.item.longitude], 15);
    L.marker([parseFloat(this.item.latitude), parseFloat(this.item.longitude)], {alt: this.item.siteId}).addTo(this.map).bindTooltip(this.item.address1)
  }
}
```

I have tried everything I have found in similar issues, but nothing worked for me.
For example, I don't understand why the console log in the first line of the **initMap()** function, is returning me undefined and instead, the **L.map()** function is returning me the error that the map has already existed...

Looking forward to helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this solution

change html `<div id="mapDetails" #leafletMap></div>`
change ts file

```
@ViewChild('leafletMap')
private mapElement: ElementRef;

    this.map = L.map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
          center: [40.4379543, -3.6795367],
          zoom: 6,
        });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-component-8ygndy

Comment: Also, put the map initialization code inside ngAfterViewInit

Comment: sorry forgot to tell